# Enterprise Program - Deploy also on app store

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile

With the Apple FAQ, I know I can not deploy on the app store if I am enrolled in an iOS Developer Enterprise Program (https://developer.apple.com/support/ios/enterprise.html). I understand that I have to create a standard iOS Developer Program to do that.

The point I don't understand is how to manage it on my xcode?

As a developer, how can I be part of an enterprise program and a standard program? Because I want to continue to develop application for the in-house, but I also want to be able to deploy some other applications on the app store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The provisioning profile you select when building an release version of you app is what identifiers if the app is an Ad-Hoc, Enterprise or appstore version.

You can therefor easily create targets for each type.

Comment: Is it on the Build Settings -> Code Signing?

Comment: Yes, that the key you want. In the release section of `Code Signing Identity` you select with which provisioning profile you want to sign the app.